# How to get the optimum performance levels and to maintain the readability

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap, refactoring

Pls note that **dueTransfersMap** lists customer_consignee and it's transfer amounts E.g #cust_ABC , 120

**dueTransfersCountMap**  lists counts for respective customer_consginee.  **DOUBLE_AT** 
      refers as a delimiter

```
        Map<String, BigDecimal> dueTransfersMap = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
        Map<String, Long> dueTransfersCountMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        BigDecimal dueCustomerConsigneeTransferTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        Long dueCustomerConsigneeTransferCount = 1L;

        for (DueCustomerAndConsigneeTransferData dueTransferRecord : dueTransferRecordList) {
            String sKey = dueTransferRecord.getCustomerName() + Symbol.DOUBLE_AT.getValue() + dueTransferRecord.getConsigneeName();

            if (dueTransferRecord.getCustomerConsigneeTransferWeight() != null) {
                dueCustomerConsigneeTransferTotal = dueTransferRecord.getCustomerConsigneeTransferWeight();
            }

            if (dueTransfersMap.containsKey(sKey)) {
                dueTransfersMap.put(sKey, dueTransfersMap.get(sKey).add(dueCustomerConsigneeTransferTotal));
                dueTransfersCountMap.put(sKey, dueTransfersCountMap.get(sKey) + dueCustomerConsigneeTransferCount);
            } else {
                dueTransfersMap.put(sKey, dueCustomerConsigneeTransferTotal);
                dueTransfersCountMap.put(sKey, dueCustomerConsigneeTransferCount);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So if `getCustomerConsigneeTransferWeight()` returns null, the value of `dueCustomerConsigneeTransferTotal` should be value left over from previous loop iteration?

Comment: For potential better performance, use [`merge(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), though I doubt the gain is really that noticeable.

Comment: @Andreas thats the way it supposed to collect # counts